# Read/write to a table using arrays

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables, listobject

I have read that that reading and writing data from a table (List Object) is more efficient using an array.
I know how to save my table into an array, but I am not sure how to read from it and add/edit the data in it.

My table has an ID column and other properties listed in the other columns.
Currently, I am searching the first column of my table for the ID and returning the row
I then search for the property(string) I am looking for in the header and return the column number
I then use both the row and column number to get the range which I can read/write

How do I do this using arrays and in the most efficient way possible?
My table holds the information of shapes, which I drag/drop and updates frequently.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Which part of this is giving you problems?

Comment: I have tried saving my table into an array. I know how to find if my ID is in the array but not how to manipulate the data in the array or find the row of the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A Table (ListObject) Lookup

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GetTableMatchTEST()

    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1")
    
    Dim Result As Variant: Result = GetTableMatch(5, tbl, 1, "Name")
    If Not IsEmpty(Result) Then
        Debug.Print Result ' 6
    End If
    
End Sub

Function GetTableMatch( _
    ByVal LookupValue As Variant, _
    ByVal tbl As ListObject, _
    ByVal LookupColumnID As Variant, _
    ByVal MatchColumnID As Variant) _
As Variant
    
    If tbl Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim lrg As Range: Set lrg = tbl.ListColumns(LookupColumnID).DataBodyRange
    Dim mrg As Range: Set mrg = tbl.ListColumns(MatchColumnID).DataBodyRange
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If lrg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If mrg Is Nothing Then Exit Function

    Dim rIndex As Variant: rIndex = Application.Match(LookupValue, lrg, 0)
    If IsError(rIndex) Then Exit Function
    
    GetTableMatch = mrg.Cells(rIndex).Value
    
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. I see that you there are a few checks in place to prevent errors from occurring, what is this called? I want to learn more on when and where to do this in my code. Will modifying this code to return the rIndex so I can edit the data in the range be correct or is there a better method?

Comment: Another good option would be to create a reference to the resulting cell range: `Function GetTableMatchingCell(...) As Range` and `Set GetTableMatchingCell = mrg.Cells(rIndex)`. Your idea could be done with: `Function GetTableRowIndex (...) As Long: GetTableRowIndex = rIndex`. But be careful because that's not the worksheet's row nor the table's row (it's the `tbl.DataBodyRange.Row`) and you are inviting yourself to complications in your `Sub` procedure or in your function. But it is doable and a good way to learn. When you get stuck you can always ask another question.

Comment: I like to call it validating (mostly objects). if you accidentally forget to set the table then `If tbl Is Nothing...` will take care of it. If you use an invalid `...ColumnID`, an error will occur, so you wrap the lines in the 'On Error construct' and afterward test if the objects to be referenced are `Nothing`. If the lookup value is found, then `rIndex` will be a whole number (otherwise an error value). If all those 'validation tests' are passed, you've arrived at the last line which returns the result. If any of the 'tests' have failed the result remains the default variant value: `Empty`.

Comment: I've implemented your code and it work excellently. Could you please help with when I have to add a new line into the table?

Comment: Also deleting rows in the table.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use an array for this task. Please consider this function which retrieves the value you want. Basically, it simulates an INDEX/MATCH action.

```
Private Function ShapeInfo(ByVal RowID As Variant, _
                           ByVal ClmID As String) As Variant

    Dim Clm     As Long
    
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
        Clm = Application.Match(ClmID, .Range.Rows(1), 0)
        If Clm Then
            ShapeInfo = Application.VLookup(RowID, .DataBodyRange, Clm, False)
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

For the purpose of testing, I entered this formula in a blank cell (any cell but I chose B4), `=ROW()*COLUMN()`. I then copied the formula to a random range based on the cell with the formula (B4:E9 in my example) and converted the range to a table. This added column headers like "Column1", 2, 3 and 4. Now the function call below will return "28".

```
Sub Demo()
    Debug.Print ShapeInfo(14, "Column3")
End Sub
```

If the `ClmID` isn't found the function will return 0. If the `RowID` isn't found, the return will be "Error 2042". You might trap these errors in the function to return something you can use as a default. Or you can trap them in the calling procedure to take some action that suits your purposes.

However, to answer your question, the snippet below will read the entire table (`DataBodyRange` excludes headers and totals) into a 2-D array, shows you how to address one of its values, change that value and write the array back to the table first above described. The value in D7 is changed, the formula replaced with the hard value set in the code.

```
Private Sub Snippet()

    Dim Arr     As Variant
    
    Arr = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Value
    Debug.Print Arr(4, 3)           ' prints 28
    
    Arr(4, 3) = 56
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Value = Arr
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you that seems like a much more elegant method than what I was doing. How do I edit the data when I want to change it to another value?

Comment: Is doing the vlookup faster than saving to an array and then reading it?

Comment: Yes, by an estimate, it should be about 10 times faster.

Comment: The shape info function returns the value in the table but how to I change the value to something else? Is it better to get the function to return the range instead?

Comment: Your question is answered by the procedure `Snippet` where the table is read into an array, changed and written back to the table, all without any function.. The function `ShapeInfo` was designed in response to your question the procedure `Snippet` was added in anticipation of the question you now ask. So, yes, there are many ways to use the demonstrated method.